# Function to produce a product description from a version, product, and some transformation rules

Tags: javascript

The following is a function that I am working on:

```
    function descFormatter(version, product) {
      formattedDescription = '';
      if (version.includes('aef')) {
        product = product.replace("^", "*");
        formattedDescription = `${version}:${product}`;
      }

      if (version.includes('eef_{placeholder}')) {
        version = version.replace("{placeholder}", product);
        formattedDescription = `${version}-${product}`;
      }
    
      if (product.match(/[^\/.]*\.[^\/]*$/) && version.includes('eef')) {
        formattedDescription = `${version}-${product}-old)`;
      }

      return formattedDescription;
    }
```

It basically generates a description by applying changes to the parameters, depending on their values.
I know that the number of these ifs will not stop increasing and I need to find a way to make it maintainable.

My attempt:

```
  function DescriptionFormatter(version, product) {
    this.firstRule  = (version, product) => version.includes('aef');
    this.secondRule = (version, product) => version.includes('eef_{placeholder}');
    this.thirdRule  = (version, product) => product.match(/[^\/.]*\.[^\/]*$/) && version.includes('eef');

    const rulesMap = {
      firstRule:  (version, product) => `${version}:${product.replace("^", "*")}`,
      secondRule: (version, product) => `${version.replace("{placeholder}", product)}-${product}`,
      thirdRule:  (version, product) => `${version}-${product}-old`
    }

    return function() {
      let formattedDescription = `${version}-${product}`;
      Object.keys(rulesMap).forEach((key) => {
        if (this[key](version, product) === true) {
          formattedDescription = rulesMap[key](version, product);
          return;
        };
      });
      return formattedDescription;
    } 
  }

  function descFormatter(version, product) {
    const formatter = DescriptionFormatter(version, product);
    console.log(formatter());        
  }
  
  descFormatter('aef', 'pick^red');
  // aef:pick*red 

  descFormatter('eef_{placeholder}', 'string10');
  // eef_string10-string10

  descFormatter('eef_string11', 'nylon/.11')
  // eef_string11-nylon/.11-old
```

So instead of slapping check after check in the original function, we add the check as a local variable in DescriptionFormatter and the callback action in the rulesMap object.

This is just a quick draft without any refinement, there are probably things I could further do like put firstRule, secondRule in some config var, or perhaps put both the checks and the actions in one object.

Is this a good idea? Is it readable enough? Would you do something differently?

Update for clarification: The cases will not depend from each other, the result from one rule won't be used in other rules. This should basically be a replacement for a long switch statement.

Comment: This question is too sketchy. What for you mean by "let's say we have…" — is that your real code (which is one of the requirements for Code Review — see the [help/on-topic])? What really happens in the "do something" placeholder? Does the order of the rules matter (i.e. should the output from one rule get transformed again by subsequent rules)?

Comment: @200_success, "What for you mean by "let's say we have…" - It's a function that I started writing and figured out there had to be a better way before it becomes unwieldy. "What really happens in the "do something" placeholder" - A placeholder for some random transformation that would eventually happen, just to paint a picture. And the order doesn't really matter, each will be independent from other.

Comment: Please fill in the "do something" placeholder and remove the hypothetical language before requesting a review.

Comment: I updated the question. I went through the help section, It seems that the question in it's original form wasn't a good fit for this forum at all, I apologise for that.